# AddOAuth is not defining the Callbackpath specified (getting a 404 on it) - ASP .NET Core 3

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to implement an OAuth2 client using ASP.NET Core 3 application. Here is how I add OAuth to my startup

```
services.AddAuthentication(config => 
{
    config.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Client.Auth.Cookie";
    config.DefaultSignInScheme = "Client.Auth.Cookie";

    config.DefaultChallengeScheme = "SelfServer";

})
    .AddCookie("Client.Auth.Cookie")
    .AddOAuth("SelfServer", config =>
    {
        config.CallbackPath = "/oauth/callback";
        config.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://Server/oauth/authorize";
        config.TokenEndpoint = "https://Server/oauth/token";
        config.ClientId = "clientid";
        config.ClientSecret = "secret_key";
    });
```

As I read in the documentation, the `/oauth/callback` is something I do not have to define myself (no need to create OAuthController with Callback action). I kind of by mistake did it and defined it myself, then when I realized, I deleted the OAuthController and now I am getting a 404 on https://client/oauth/callback.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I realized a few seconds after posting this question that I forgot to call

```
app.UseAuthentication()
```

in my `Configure()` method in the `Startup`.